# Is there a robust \renewcommand replacement?

Tags: macros, expansion

Replacing `\newcommand` by `\DeclareRobustCommand` makes a new command robust. But what about `\renewcommand`? Is there a command to robustly renew a command?

It would be possible to first use `\renewcommand` and then use `\MakeRobustCommand` of the [makerobust](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makerobust) package, but isn't there a "one-command-way"? (And does that one provide a starred form, same as `\DeclareRobustCommand*`?)

Comment: I'm not sure but you may want to look into  `\NewDocumentCommand` from [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3packages).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) command provides a `\renewrobustcmd` macro as well as a `\newrobustcmd` (and their starred versions). Both use the new e-TeX way to define robust commands. Note that `\DeclareRobustCommand` is not checking if the command already exists and will not cause any errors if it does. This might result in trouble when a macro is defined twice on two different places and you don't know about it. The `etoolbox` macro include the checks.

Comment: > "`\DeclareRobustCommand` is not checking if the command already exists and will not cause any errors if it does." - That is exactly the reason because of which I asked for a robust `\renewcommand` version. As I did not state that, it is good that you wrote it in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephen: Without `etoolbox` you could also redefine the macro with a dummy `\renewcommand` to check if it exists and then use `\DeclareRobustCommand` to redefine it in a robust way.