# Are commands defined by \newcommand[.][.]{.} robust?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, latex-base

This question is from the comments at the foot of  [Abbreviations for AM, PM (small caps) for use within \textbf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60042/abbreviations-for-am-pm-small-caps-for-use-within-textbf/60054#60054). Readers will get the remaining gist from there.

With

```
\newcommand\cmd[2][0]{\def\y{#1}}
\edef\x{\cmd{1}}
```

I get

```
{\edef}

\cmd ->\@protected@testopt \cmd \\cmd {0}

\@protected@testopt #1->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \expandafter \@testopt
\else \@x@protect #1\fi
#1<-\cmd
{\ifx}
{true}
{\expandafter}
{\else}

\@testopt #1#2->\kernel@ifnextchar [{#1}{#1[{#2}]}
#1<-\\cmd
#2<-0

\kernel@ifnextchar #1#2#3->\let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reser
ved@b {#3}\futurelet \@let@token \@ifnch
#1<-[
#2<-\\cmd
#3<-\\cmd [{0}]

\reserved@a #11#2{->\expandafter \def \expandafter \\cmd \reserved@b #11{
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
<to be read again>
                   }
l.3103 \edef\x{\cmd{1}}

? x
```

Is that robustness? See also [Is there a robust \renewcommand replacement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28698/is-there-a-robust-renewcommand-replacement).

Comment: I thought it is not and that is why there is `\DeclareRobustCommand` which has the same parameter syntax as `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using

```
\newcommand{\foo}[...][...]
```

creates a macro `\foo` which has definition

```
\@protected@testopt \foo \\foo {...}
```

Inside a LaTeX 'protected expansion' command (`\protected@edef`, `\protected@xdef`, `\protected@write`), the definition of `\@protected@testopt` is altered such that no further expansion takes place, so that

```
\protected@edef\test{\foo}
\show\test
```

gives

```
> \test=macro:
->\protect \foo .
```

`\DeclareRobustCommand` works slightly differently, as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[...][...]
```

gives a definition

```
> \foo=macro:
->\protect \foo  .
```

where there is a space in the name of that internal macro: it's called '`\foo` '. Doing a 'protected expansion' here gives

```
> \test=macro:
->\protect \foo  .
```

*i.e.* the 'name with space' is retained. As this method adds `\protect` 'earlier' than the mechanism used by `\newcommand`, this is more robust at the cost of an additional cname.

Neither of these mechanisms will prevent expansion inside a plain `\edef`, `\xdef` or `\write`. For that, you need the e-TeX protected mechanism, which is wrapped up in a `\newcommand`-like way by `\newrobustcmd` from the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. There, doing

```
\newrobustcmd{\foo}[...][...]
```

gives a definition

```
> \foo=\protected macro:
->\@testopt \\foo {...}.
```

This will *never* expand in an expansion context, as the engine is doing the protection.

Answer (score 12):

The concepts of "fragility" and "robustness" are proper of LaTeX; a robust command is one that survives being in the replacement text for `\protected@edef` or `\protected@write`. It has *nothing* to do with surviving `\edef` or `\write`.

For example, after

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[1][bar]{...}
```

something like

```
\edef\baz{\foo[x]}
```

will fail with

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }
```

Conversely, `\protected@edef\baz{\foo[x]}` will assign `\baz` the meaning

```
\protect \foo  [x]
```

(notice the *two* spaces after `\foo`). If we do instead

```
\newcommand\foo[1][bar]{...}
\protected@edef\baz{\foo[x]}
```

the meaning of `\baz` will be

```
\protect \foo [x]
```

(only one space after `\foo`). The robustifying method is different but equally effective. It must be noted that the robustifying is *not* applied when `\newcommand` is in its simple form `\newcommand\foo[n]{...}`.

Of course, `\protected` gives a robustness of a superior type, because a command defined with `\protected\def` will even survive `\edef`. But it's another story.

---

How does it work? When `\newcommand\foo[1][bar]{...}` is executed, LaTeX actually does

```
\def\foo{\@protected@testopt \foo \\foo {bar}}
```

and

```
\expandafter\def\csname\string\foo\endcsname[#1]{...}
```

which is very similar to the LaTeX2.09 way

```
\def\foo{\@testopt\@foo{bar}}
\def\@foo[#1]{...}
```

but has `\@protected@testopt` which is, essentially "if `\protect` equals `\relax`, then execute `\@testopt\\foo`, otherwise output `\protect\foo`". There's a small complication for taking care of "control symbols" such as `\?`, but this is pretty much the truth.

Comment: So there is a difference in robustness between `\newcommand` with and without an optional argument? Is the one with the optional argument made robust in order to protect the default value?

Comment: @canaaerus Protecting commands having an optional argument is necessary (actually something could be done, as proved in `xparse`, but it's quite a delicate feature). Protecting "normal" commands is usually undesirable: otherwise `\write` operations would never record current information such as the page or section number.

Comment: @AhmedMusa I'm sure that if `\protected` had been available all the `\protect` thing would never have existed. But under the current state of affairs, commands having an optional argument defined with `\newcommand` *are* robust as far as LaTeX is concerned.

Comment: It's pointless arguing with egreg, who has been teaching (or using) TeX since 1987, but for some of us who are new comers, we understand robustness the eTeX (and hence *etoolbox*'s) way. Times change. I personally will prefer that robustness is an intrinsic property that doesn't depend on the current state or value of `\protect` or any command. Commands whose values are to be recorded in any file at runtime should, in this case, not be robustified in any way.

Comment: My view is that if eTeX was available in the 1980s, Leslie Lamport would probably have preferred `\protected` to `\@protected@testopt`. **egreg has responded to this above**.

Answer (score 5):

Such macros use the protect mechanism of LaTeX and will only work in a `\protected@edef` and other LaTeX macros, e.g. the aux-file writing macros, which set `\protect` accordantly. They are not meant to work in a general expanding context like `\edef` or a normal `\write`.

If you need to define a robust LaTeX macro with optional argument use the core macro `\DeclareRobustCommand` or `\newrobustcmd` from the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: The second paragraph is not correct. `\DeclareRobustCommand` creates commands which will not expand inside `\protected@edef`, but will still go wrong inside `\edef`. For that, you need the e-TeX mechanism.