# commands with optional arguments in \write

Tags: optional-arguments, write

To extract text from huge LaTeX-files in a safe and controllable manner, I am having LaTeX itself write to a textfile. To retain and adapt some formatting informations and structural elements I have given the file a new header where I redefine the commands for this special purpose. This works fine until I need commands with optional arguments.

Using `newfile` for convenience:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{out}
\openoutputfile{out.text}{out}


\newcommand{\standardexample}[3]{#1:#2(#3)}
\newcommand{\optionalexample}[3][default]{#1:#2(#3)}

\begin{document}

text \standardexample{1}{2}{3} and \optionalexample[not default]{2}{3} or \optionalexample{2}{3}

\addtostream{out}{
text \standardexample{1}{2}{3} and \optionalexample[not default]{2}{3} or \optionalexample{2}{3}
}

\closeoutputstream{out}

\end{document}
```

I get

> text 1:2(3) and not default:2(3) or default:2(3)

in the pdf as expected, but

> text 1:2(3) and \optionalexample[not default]{2}{3} or \optionalexample{2}{3}

in the text-file with no errors in the log.

Testing without `newfile`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\standardexample}[3]{#1:#2(#3)}
\newcommand{\optionalexample}[3][default]{#1:#2(#3)}


\newwrite\tempfile

\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.tmp
\immediate\write\tempfile{text \standardexample{1}{2}{3} and \optionalexample[not default]{2}{3} or \optionalexample{2}{3}}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile


text \standardexample{1}{2}{3} and \optionalexample[not default]{2}{3} or \optionalexample{2}{3}


\end{document}
```

the typesetting is broken off by a couple of error messages (some of which are even included in the tmp-file), but I can't really make sense of them.

Both an expanation and a workaround would be great.

Comment: You have to use `\protected@write` or the `\immediate` variant defined in [Writing ``\\`` to a file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110883/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands defined with an optional argument are automatically robustified, but this means they survive `\protected@write`; they definitely don't survive `\write` exactly because of the protection mechanism.

It mostly depends on what you want to write to the auxiliary file; if you need the *expansion* of those commands you're out of luck, because they must perform assignments in order to produce their replacement text.

With `\protected@write`, an input such as

```
\protected@write\tempfile{}{\optionalexample[not default]{2}{3} or \optionalexample{2}{3}}
```

would write

```
text \optionalexample [not default]{2}{3} or \optionalexample {2}{3}
```

You can find an `\immediate` version in [Writing \\ to a File](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110883/)

If you instead need the full expansion of the commands, you can use `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\optionalexample}{O{default}mm}{#1:#2(#3)}
```

and this will work in `\immediate\write`.

---

You can find some discussion about a macro with optional argument defined with `\newcommand` at [Are commands defined by \newcommand[.][.]{.} robust?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60353/are-commands-defined-by-newcommand-robust)

There you can see that your `\optionalexample` macro becomes, when TeX expands it

```
\@protected@testopt \optionalexample \\optionalexample {default}
```

Now the problem starts: when you do `\immediate\write`, the value of `\protect` is `\@typeset@protect` (which in turn means `\relax`, but it's irrelevant. Here's the definition of `\@protected@testopt`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 619:
\def\@protected@testopt#1{%%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \expandafter\@testopt
  \else
    \@x@protect#1%
  \fi}
```

In this case the conditional returns true, so TeX is presented with

```
\@testopt \optionalexample \\optionalexample {default}
```

What does `\@testopt` do? Here it is:

```
% latex.ltx, line 617:
\long\def\@testopt#1#2{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{#1}{#1[{#2}]}}
```

and this is the culprit! During a `\write` only macro expansion is performed, not assignments, so `\kernel@ifnextchar` cannot work, because it does `\futurelet` in order to scan the following token.

Comment: "they must perform assignments in order to produce their replacement text" isn't really clear to me. Is there a comprehensive description of what is going on internally when defining optional arguments anywhere on SE? Anyway: `xparse` is doing precisely what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Florian I added some comments and a link