# Where's the mistake? #1 inside \caption

Tags: captions, labels, showlabels

I am trying to automatically convert `\caption{...\label{...}...}` to `\caption{...}\label{...}`. This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\newcommand{\storelabel}[1]{\gdef\storedlabel{#1}}
\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{%
    \let\storedlabel\undefined
    \oldcaption{%
        \def\label##1{%
            \protect\storelabel{##1}%
        }%
        #1%
    }%
    \ifdefined\storedlabel%
        \label{\storedlabel}%
    \else%
    \fi%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{no label}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{\label{mylabel}label inside caption (front)}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{label inside caption (back) \label{mylabel}}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{label directly after caption}
        \label{mylabel}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{label at end of table (I'm OK with that one)}
        foo
        \label{mylabel}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The pdf file looks correct, too, but I get this error message (five times, once per call of `\caption`):

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.20        \caption{no label}

You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

If I replace `\storelabel{##1}` by `\storelabel{mylabel}`, the pdf file looks the same and the error message is gone. But this is not what I want, obviously.

**Update**: This MWE nicely shows the same error, *although it is unrelated to my original goal of moving `\label` out of `\caption` and thereby moving the `showlabels` labels*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{\def\foo[#1]{#1}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\caption` has an (moving) optional argument which gets lost here -- I fear that your approach screws up the whole labelling system

Comment: Instead of all this trickery, why not simply use your editor or a tool like `sed` to make the changes in fact? (Aside from the fun the intellectual challenge may provide, for actual documents, it may be better to subscribe to the philosophy that just because TeX *can* do something doesn't mean you *should* use TeX to do it.)

Comment: The basic error (in my point of view) is that you try to redefine `\caption` with an argument -- it's in fact an moving argument. If the `caption` package` is loaded, those whole redefinitions would break again (even if they would work right now)

Comment: @jon the reason is a table macro from a document class that I use (`iopart`, to be exact), which uses `\label` inside `\caption`. @ChristianHupfer I agree for my particular application; but my redefinition of `\caption` could be replaced by an appropriate `xpatchcmd` that takes optional and moving arguments into account . Anyway, there seems to be something else I am doing wrong: look at the first short MWE, for example, where I reproduce the same error without any redefinition of `\caption`. It does not even have to involve `\label`, as the last short MEW now shows.

Comment: Your update has you `\def`-ing `\protect?

Comment: Seems so :) I was trying to reduce the number of errors (3) to only those regarding the use of #1 within `\caption`. I assume now, by the way, that this problem is mainly robustness (or lack thereof), and should simply be avoided as in my answer below: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60353/are-commands-defined-by-newcommand-robust

Comment: By the way: I looked at `iopart.cls`. Although its guidelines tell us to put `\label` in `\caption`, there is nothing in the class code that requires you to do so (and is 'wrong' from a LaTeX point of view -- see the *LaTeX2e* manual) unless you use the `\Table` macro. But that is a dirty hack that you should probably avoid anyway since it defines a table of 16 columns and then lets you input a table of fewer columns by relying on `\\ ` to prematurely end each row.

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, it's better to catch the `\label` and let it store the label name to `\storedlabel` in `\caption` and then shift the real `\label` to the end of `\@caption`, after the `\@makecaption` has been issued.

The redefinition of `\label` will break `cleveref`'s `\label[...]{foo}` style!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{cleveref} % Just for testing!

\makeatletter

\LetLtxMacro\latex@@origlabel\label

\xpatchcmd{%
  \caption
}{%
  \refstepcounter\@captype%
}{%
  \let\storedlabel\undefined%
  \refstepcounter\@captype
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
     \gdef\storedlabel{##1}%  Catch the  the label but doing nothing except of storing it!
   }
   \endgroup
 }{\typeout{Successfully patched caption}}{\typeout{Failed in patching caption}}


\xpatchcmd{\@caption}{%
  \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}{%
  \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup%
  \@ifundefined{storedlabel}{}{%  Transfer the label to this place
    \label@@origlabel{\storedlabel}}%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
        \caption{no label}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{\label{othermylabel}label inside caption (front)}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{label inside caption (back) \label{mylabel}}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{label directly after caption}
        \label{mylabelfoo}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{label at end of table (I'm OK with that one)}
      foo
      \label{mylabelfoobar}
    \end{table}

Now some referencing: \cref{othermylabel} and \ref{mylabel} and \ref{mylabelfoo} and \ref{mylabelfoobar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I may not have been clear enough about my goal, which is to move all `showlabels` labels to the right margin. Your table 2 still looks like the original version using no patch at all, with the label within the table caption instead of to its right.

Comment: @bers: Look into your question: There's **no** single word indicating that you want to move the showlabels stuff! Thanks for wasting my time :-(

Comment: I am sorry this could be misunderstand. I did not see any other reason to move `\label` out of `\caption` instead of `showlabels` because this is the first time that I have ever been seeing a difference between the two. Probably there are more cases, but I did not think of that. Anyway, your try was very helpful to me as you will see in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\def\storelabel#1{\gdef\storedlabel{#1}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{#3}{\global\let\storedlabel\undefined\let\label\storelabel#3}{}{err}
\apptocmd{\@caption}{\ifdefined\storedlabel\label{\storedlabel}\else\fi}{}{err}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \clearpage
    \begin{table}
        \caption{no label}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{\label{mylabel}label inside caption (front)}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{label inside caption (back) \label{mylabel}}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{label directly after caption}
        \label{mylabel}
        foo
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{label at end of table (I'm OK with that one)}
        foo
        \label{mylabel}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The key differences are

- `\def\label##1{...}` -> `\let\label\storelabel`, avoiding the use of the argument `##1` within `\caption`
- Inspired by and thanks to @ChristianHupfer, the use of `xpatch` to selectively patch `\@caption` instead of redefining `\caption`. It even works with the `caption` package and with `\listoftables` now.

His comment still stands: `\label` with an optional argument fails. But I do not need that.